# Rails 3, change or fill submitted form values in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-submit, before-save

I have two independent "component" models, contacts and articles. Contacts come in many types (producers, exporters etc...).

In the new article form I have a dropdown selector with contacts (id and title) and want to store the selected **value and text** in the article table.

In the new article form view:

```
<%= f.select :producer_id, options_for_select(producers, @article.producer_id) %>
```

That works and `producer_id` is stored in article table.

That's clear and logical to me, but in some cases I also need to store the selected contact's title in `producer_title`.

I have read many different options like "do it in model, before save", or "do it in controller", and I have done it inside controller.

Article controller (only part from update):

```
#cont_name is producer title from Contacts
def update
  params[:article][:producer_title] = Contact.where(id: params[:article][:producer_id]).pluck(:cont_name).first 
end
```

This works, but is it the best-practices approach to this problem?

Also, why I can't get it to work if I change the `params[producer_id]` part to use: `id: params[:producer_id]` ?

Best regards and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the following instead:

```
def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @producers = Contact.where(type: "producer") # or however you distinguish between producers and other contacts
end
```

Then in your form change it to:

```
f.select :producer_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@producers, "cont_name")
# you might need to do (@producers, "cont_name", "cont_name"), can't quite remember
```

Then your update action will be much simpler:

```
def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

The reason `:id => params[:producer_id]` doesn't work is that `params` is a nested hash, so something like:

```
params = { :article => { :producer_id => 34, :title => "Cool Article" }, :another_key => { :key => :value } }
```

So to access the `producer_id` you first have to retrieve the `article` hash, otherwise it will only look through the first set of keys which include `article` and `another_key` in the example above, but don't include `producer_id`.